# FlashDevelop - Why does code-completion not work with mx.controls

Tags: apache-flex, flashdevelop

Today's my first day with Flex and FlashDevelop. In my ActionScript file, I have this line.

```
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
```

FlashDevelop is aware about this and Code-completion works fine.

But, when I have this line.

```
import mx.controls.Button;
```

Then code-completion doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Works perfectly well for me w/o doing anything special. But maybe your project's properties got borked. Do this:

Open Project Properties
Go to Compiler Options tab
In Advanced -> Intrinsic Libraries add the following
Library\AS3\frameworks\Flex3

Comment: +1 helped with `Library\AS3\frameworks\Flex4` as well as for `spark.components`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Your AS3 class path is pointing at a directory to low in the flashdevelop library folder structure to pick the mx class prototypes.

1.) Within Flashdevelop press F10 to open the 'Settings' window.

2.) In the list on the left click on the 'AS3Context' option.

3.) Imediately Under the group title of 'Language' on the right hand side of the window, find the 'AS3 Classpath' option.  Its value is typically set to 'Library\AS3\Intrinsic'.  Change the the 'AS3 Classpath' value to read 'Library\AS3'.

4.) FIXED.  Flashdevelop should now be aware of the mx libraries, thus autocomplete should now also work.

Answer (score 1):

To include any swc to code complete, add it's parent folder to the swc libraries option. Some people claim that using intrinsic libraries works, but it didn't for me. Here's the paths to both settings:

```
ProjectSettings->CompilerOptions->SWCLibraries = {path to FOLDER containing swc's}
ProjectSettings->CompilerOptions->IntrinsicLibraries = {path to same FOLDER containing swc's}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the Flex framework in your build path. Have you looked at the libraries being included?