# Best Class for base64 encoding/decoding Action Script?

Tags: actionscript-3, base64

What would be a best Class for base64 encryption/decryption in Action Script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adobe has two utils for this - [Base64Encoder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.html) & [Base64Decoder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/Base64Decoder.html). Both are located in the mx.utils package. Although, I had to track them down here - [encoder](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.as) & [decoder](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/utils/Base64Decoder.as).

The usage would be something like:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = myBitmap.bitmapData;
var ba:ByteArray = bmd.getPixels(new Rectangle(0,0,bmd.width,bmd.height));
var b64:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
b64.encodeBytes(ba);
trace(b64.toString());
```

Similarly, 'b64.encode' would encode a String rather than a ByteArray.

Both the encoder and decoder add their respective results to an internal buffer. So, you just have to use 'toString' to return the current buffer.

Comment: For some reason, the [documentation on their site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.html) is incomplete.  Fortunately, the correct documentation shows up under FlashBuilder's auto-complete feature.

Comment: I would go with this hurlant package also.

Comment: +1! works out of the box, no need to bundle any special files. Note: if you don't see the mx package in FlashDevelop, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524893/flashdevelop-why-does-code-completion-not-work-with-mx-controls).

Comment: Flex has been moved to the apache servers. Here are the new paths to files Сorey mentioned:
[Base64Encoder](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-sdk/repo?p=flex-sdk.git&a=blob&f=frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.as&hb=refs/heads/master)
[Base64Decoder](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/flex-sdk/repo?p=flex-sdk.git&a=blob&f=frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/utils/Base64Decoder.as&hb=refs/heads/master)

Answer (score 2):

This one seems to have some legs/supporters:  http://garry-lachman.com/2010/04/21/base64-encoding-class-in-actionscript-3/

Answer (score 2):

At this link you will find a good Base64 class:
http://www.sociodox.com/base64.html

Answer (score 2):

[`blooddy_crypto`](http://www.blooddy.by/en/crypto/) claims (according to it's benchmark) to have a faster base64 encoder/decoder than the `mx.utils` one.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the packages that I have seen that include one as a support function use the one that is credited to Steve Webster.  I do not know which package this started out in, but it appears in several libraries, including the [as3crypto lib](https://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) on Google Code.