# How to decode the base64 encoded ios app store receipt in as3 air sdk

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, base64, receipt-validation

how do I decode the base64 encoded ios app store receipt with Air SDK?

Found this Base64 class in as3 doc:
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/Base64Encoder.html
But it is not present Air SDK 29, doh! and have tried similar open source libs without luck.

Here is what I try to achieve: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1

Comment: If you want to **decode** Base64, the Base64**Encoder** won't do you much good in the first place :-) Also, [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625347/best-class-for-base64-encoding-decoding-action-script)

Comment: Doh! wrong link. But after changed Ane library to Freshplanet's I realized that I misunderstood the whole receipt part. Thanks for the reply :-)